# Spring Data JPA with QueryDSL issue with JPA Inheritance.JOINED strategy when subclasses have the same property name

Tags: jpa

I am trying to use QueryDSL for a dynamic query that I need to do.  This is a Spring Boot project with QueryDSL 3.7.2 (com.mysema.querydsl).  I have simplified the example, but basically I have an Item abstract class annotated with with an Inheritance.JOINED strategy.  This is the Item class:

```
package org.porthos.concepts.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorColumn;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "item_type")
public abstract class Item {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "item_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private ItemType type;

  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  protected Item() {}

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public ItemType getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Item [id=" + id + ", type=" + type + "]";
  }

}
```

There are also 2 sub classes that extend Item.  Those are Book, and CD.

Book:

```
package org.porthos.concepts.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
@DiscriminatorValue("BOOK")
public class Book extends Item {
  @Column(name = "genre")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private BookGenre genre;

  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  public static enum BookGenre {
    MYSTERY, HISTORY, SCIENCE, COMPUTER;
  }

  protected Book() {}

  public Book(BookGenre genre, String title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.title = title;
  }

  public BookGenre getGenre() {
    return genre;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Book [genre=" + genre + ", title=" + title + ", getId()=" +    getId() + ", getType()="
        + getType() + "]";
  }

}
```

And CD:

```
package org.porthos.concepts.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cd")
@DiscriminatorValue("CD")
public class CD extends Item {
  @Column(name = "genre")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private CDGenre genre;

  @Column(name = "title")
  private String title;

  public static enum CDGenre {
    CLASSICAL, POP, ROCK, BLUES;
  }

  protected CD() {}

  public CD(CDGenre genre, String title) {
    this.title = title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.title = title;
  }

  public CDGenre getGenre() {
    return genre;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "CD [genre=" + genre + ", title=" + title + ", getId()=" + getId() + ", getType()="
        + getType() + "]";
  }

}
```

This is the Test class that I am using for testing:

```
package org.porthos.concepts;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.porthos.concepts.domain.Book;
import org.porthos.concepts.domain.Book.BookGenre;
import org.porthos.concepts.domain.CD;
import org.porthos.concepts.domain.CD.CDGenre;
import org.porthos.concepts.domain.Item;
import org.porthos.concepts.domain.QBook;
import org.porthos.concepts.domain.QItem;
import org.porthos.concepts.repository.ItemRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.mysema.query.BooleanBuilder;
import com.mysema.query.types.Predicate;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ConceptsApplication.class)
@Transactional
public class QueryDslTest {

  @Autowired
  private ItemRepository itemRepository;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {}

  @Test
  public void test() {
    // Persist a Book and a CD for test
    Book book = new Book(BookGenre.SCIENCE, "How To Use Your Microscope");
    book = itemRepository.save(book);
    CD cd = new CD(CDGenre.BLUES, "The Wind Cries Mary");
    cd = itemRepository.save(cd);

    Predicate isScienceBook = QItem.item.as(QBook.class).genre.eq(BookGenre.SCIENCE);

    BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
    builder.or(isScienceBook);

    Page<Item> itemsPage = itemRepository.findAll(builder, new PageRequest(0, 10));
    assertThat(itemsPage.getContent().size(), is(1));
  }

}
```

So basically, each of the sub classes Book and CD have a **genre** property that is Typed differently.  The Book genre uses the BookGenre type and the CD genre has the CDGenre type.  The problem happens because the properties are named exactly alike.

So when I run the test which is trying to query for a Book, I get the following stack trace which is basically stating that it is expecting **genre** to be of Type CDGenre.

If I run the test with a query for a CD, the query works without any issues.

Also if I rename the Book and CD genre properties so that they're unique such as bookGenre and cdGenre, then the Book query definitely works.

So in order to use this type of inheritance I have to make sure that each of the sub classes have differently named properties.  But in this example a Genre for music CDs should not be the same as a Genre for Books, and I don't see it as necessarily wrong that they're both named **genre**.

So I'm not sure if it's bad domain design on my part, of if there's an issue with Spring Data JPA, and or QueryDSL.

Thanks,

Frank

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [SCIENCE] did not match expected type [org.porthos.concepts.domain.CD$CDGenre (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [SCIENCE] did not match expected type [org.porthos.concepts.domain.CD$CDGenre (n/a)]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.findAll(Unknown Source)
at org.porthos.concepts.QueryDslTest.test(QueryDslTest.java:54)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [SCIENCE] did not match expected type [org.porthos.concepts.domain.CD$CDGenre (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:874)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:80)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:248)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$JpaPositionalParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:337)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:674)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:198)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:49)
at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAUtil.setConstants(JPAUtil.java:55)
at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:130)
at com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.count(AbstractJPAQuery.java:81)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:468)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 38 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all working fine without QueryDSL in a Spring Boot JPA/Web framework, though I had to get rid of the `ItemType` field in `Item` since JPA provides that for you.

```
@Override
public void createBook() {
    Book book = new Book(BookGenre.SCIENCE, "How To Use Your Microscope");
    bookRepository.save(book);
    CD cd = new CD(CDGenre.BLUES, "The Wind Cries Mary");
    cdRepository.save(cd);        
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void getBook() {
    Page<Book> books = bookRepository.findByGenre(BookGenre.SCIENCE, new PageRequest(0, 20) );
    System.out.println( books.getContent().get(0) );
}
```

gives

```
Hibernate: select count(book0_.id) as col_0_0_ from book book0_ inner join item book0_1_ on book0_.id=book0_1_.id where book0_.genre=?
Hibernate: select book0_.id as id2_2_, book0_1_.title as title3_2_, book0_.genre as genre1_0_, book0_.title as title2_0_ from book book0_ inner join item book0_1_ on book0_.id=book0_1_.id where book0_.genre=? limit ?
Book [genre=SCIENCE, title=How To Use Your Microscope, getId()=1]
```